# yii2: dropdown select field with like

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, yii2

I have a drop-down select field which has long list of values, I want to select the values from the list as like search to make it easier to select the values for example in my list:

I have

```
DR X
DR Y
Dr Z
```

so if type Z, the value Dr Z is highlighted for selection. Now I have to type Dr Z to highlight the value.

My code for the drop-down list is like:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'doctor_name')->DropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Doctor::find()->all(), 'id', 'doctor_name' ),
[ 'prompt' => 'Please Select' ]) ?>
```

Looking for some hints.

Comment: It seems like you're looking for something along the lines of the jquery-ui combobox : https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: I think what you are suggesting is correct, but how to implement that. I am getting the values from the DB

Comment: May I suggest you rename your question title to include the word "combobox"?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is something along the lines of jquery Ui's combobox. How to implement this into your software can be done in multiple ways but here is one:

### Making a combobox widget

Yii2 comes with multiple jquery-ui widgets. This first step is to [install JUI for Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-jui-index.html)

Once this is done you will have access to all of those widgets. However there is no combobox widget (only a standard autocomplete one). It's ok we can still use the assets from this plugin.

**making an AssetBundle for the widget**

Create a `ComboboxAssetBundle.php` file that you'll place into the `assets` folder. It should be as follows (this is an example for the `advanced template` and `frontend` entry point):

```
namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class ComboboxAssetBundle extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@frontend/assets';
    public $css = [
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/combobox.js', // Lets load your custom JS
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset', // requires Jquery
        'yii\jui\JuiAsset', // requires JUI
    ];
}
```

Your `@frontend/assets/js/combobox.js` file should contain the combobox js code:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "custom.combobox", {
      _create: function() {
        this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
          .insertAfter( this.element );

        this.element.hide();
        this._createAutocomplete();
        this._createShowAllButton();
      },

      _createAutocomplete: function() {
        var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
          value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

        this.input = $( "<input>" )
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .val( value )
          .attr( "title", "" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
          .autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
          })
          .tooltip({
            tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
          });

        this._on( this.input, {
          autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.item.option.selected = true;
            this._trigger( "select", event, {
              item: ui.item.option
            });
          },

          autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
        });
      },

      _createShowAllButton: function() {
        var input = this.input,
          wasOpen = false;

        $( "<a>" )
          .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
          .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
          .tooltip()
          .appendTo( this.wrapper )
          .button({
            icons: {
              primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
            },
            text: false
          })
          .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
          .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
          .mousedown(function() {
            wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
          })
          .click(function() {
            input.focus();

            // Close if already visible
            if ( wasOpen ) {
              return;
            }

            // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
            input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
          });
      },

      _source: function( request, response ) {
        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
        response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
          var text = $( this ).text();
          if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
            return {
              label: text,
              value: text,
              option: this
            };
        }) );
      },

      _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {

        // Selected an item, nothing to do
        if ( ui.item ) {
          return;
        }

        // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
        var value = this.input.val(),
          valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
          valid = false;
        this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
          if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
            this.selected = valid = true;
            return false;
          }
        });

        // Found a match, nothing to do
        if ( valid ) {
          return;
        }

        // Remove invalid value
        this.input
          .val( "" )
          .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
          .tooltip( "open" );
        this.element.val( "" );
        this._delay(function() {
          this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
        }, 2500 );
        this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
      },

      _destroy: function() {
        this.wrapper.remove();
        this.element.show();
      }
    });
  })( jQuery );
```

**making the widget**

With all the above in place now you need to create the widget. To stay consistent with the above lets make a `@frontend/widgets/Combobox.php` file with the following:

```
namespace frontend\widgets;

use yii\base\Widget;
use frontend\assets\ComboboxAssetBundle;
use yii\base\InvalidConfigException;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use Yii;

class Combobox extends Widget
{
    /**
     * @var form object if desired
     */
    public $form;

    /**
     * @var model object tu use
     */
    public $model;

    /**
     * @var model attribute this dropdown is for.
     */
    public $attribute;

    /**
     * @var options for the dropdown.
     */
    public $options = [];

    /**
     * @var items for the dropdown list.
     */
    public $items = [];

    public function init()
    {
        if(!isset($this->attribute))
        {
            throw new InvalidConfigException("an attribute is required");
        }
    }

    public function run()
    {
        //register your asset:
        ComboboxAssetBundle::register(Yii::$app->view);
        Yii::$app->view->registerJs('$( ".combobox" ).combobox();');

        //add a class to the options
        $options = ArrayHelper::merge($this->options, ['class'=>'combobox']);

        if(isset($this->form))
        {
            return $this->form->field($this->model, $this->attribute)->dropDownList($this->items, $options);
        }
        elseif(isset($this->model))
        {
            return Html::activeDropDownList($this->model, $this->attribute, $this->items, $options);
        }
        else
        {
            return Html::dropDownList($this->attribute, NULL, $this->items, $options);
        }
    }
}
```

**calling the widget**

With this you should be able to call the widget with `Combobox::widget([])` like follows in your case:

```
<?= Combobox::widget([
    'form' => $form,
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'doctor_name',
    'items' => ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Doctor::find()->all(), 'id', 'doctor_name' ),
    'options' => [ 'prompt' => 'Please Select' ]) ?>
```

I haven't tested this but there should be enough information for you to get it working pretty easily. The advantage of this is that you will be able to reuse this type of dropdown anywhere in your application.

Let me know if you need any extra information.

### Edit:

Sometimes you will need to have your app forceCopy your assets or you won't see any changes. There are many ways of doing/configuring this but locally on your dev environment I find that the simplest is to add the following to your `local` configuration file:

```
'components' => [
    //...
    'assetManager' => [
        'forceCopy' => TRUE,
    ]
],
```

Comment: Hi D.Mill - Thanks for such a elaborate answer. I am using a basic template.  I have adapted the code as per the basic template. but it's working as it was originally but not as intended with like.

Comment: My bad I forgot the most important. I've corrected my answer with the following: `combobox.js` at the bottom of the file changed `#combobox` with `.combobox` . In the widget I added `use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper` at the top and I added the combobox class to the dropdowns in the `run()`. Hope it works now.

Comment: Hi - D.Mill - Still No luck. The drop-down is showing fine, but it is not working as needed.

Comment: @Pawan That's odd, it seems to work fine for me. I just tested. I made an alteration, removed the bottom part of `combobox.js` and placed it in the widget. That however shouldn't be required. Are you sure all the scripts are being loaded properly? Can you check in your navigator? (firebug or chrome dev tools)

Comment: Oh I just had an idea and edited my answer. Please change that before making any other changes :)